# How to build tree-like data according to a xlsx work sheet

Tags: java, excel, recursion

I have  a xlsx file which contain a sheet with these kinds of records:

[image]

Now I have to generate a JSON object according to these records like this:

```
[name:"group1",items:[
    {name:"a",items:[
      {name:"aa",x:30,y:20},
      {name:"ab",x:30,y:20},
      ....
    ]},
    {name:"b",items:[...]},
    {name:"c",items:[...]}]]
```

It seems that the recursion is required.

But I have no idea how to start it.

Anyone can give me some suggestion?

BTW, I use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) to read the xlsx file.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
root = new JSON array
level0 = null
level1 = null
level2 = null
for row in sheet:
   if row[0] != '':
       level0 = new Json(name:row[0], items:new List())
       root.add(level0)
       level1 = null
       level2 = null
   if row[1] != '':
       level1 = new Json(name:row[1], items:new List())
       level0.items.add(level1)
       level2 = null
   if row[2] != '':
       level2 = new Json(name:row[2], x:row[3], y:row[4])
       level1.items.add(level2)
```